# Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. but the id is already exist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, key, jsx

I'm working on an ecommerce project and I'm trying to put all the product selected in the cart dropDown that shows up in the icon. I did the key `id` but it still ask me to give an id to each child?

Where exactly am I wrong?

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import CustomButton from "../custom-button/custom-button.cpn";
import CartItem from "../cart-item/cart-item.cpn";
import "./cart-dropdown.styles.scss";

const CartDropDown = ({ cartItems }) => (
  <div className="cart-dropdown">
    <div className="cart-items">
      {cartItems.map((cartItem) => (
        <CartItem key={cartItem.id} item={cartItem}/>
      ))}
    </div>
    <CustomButton>Go to checkout</CustomButton>
  </div>
);

const mapStateToProps = ({ cart: { cartItems } }) => ({
  cartItems
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CartDropDown);
```

Cart item

```
import React from "react";
import "./cart-item.style.scss";

const CartItem = ({ item: { imageUrl, price, name, quantity } }) => (
  <div className="cart-item">
    <img src={imageUrl} alt="item" />
    <div className="item-details">
      <span className="name">{name}</span>
      <span className="price">
        {quantity} x ${price}
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default CartItem;
```

[data.json that I'm mapping in first page  ] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5nxR.png)

[Second page] [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zaw6d.png)

Comment: Either ids are not unique or it's not that array that causes the problem

Comment: Can you [edit] to include a sample of the `cartItems` data you are mapping so we can see what any `cartItem.id` values are that are used as React keys?

Comment: do you  mean  you need like a screenchot of , the datapage .json ?

Comment: Add `console.log(cartItem.id)` and see if there are duplicates. There is no `quantity` in that json so clearly you map it somewhere. Maybe you dropped the `id` by accident

Comment: quantity is set to 1 by default , & it's up to user to choose the quantity :
 
       ```jsx
 export const addItemToCart = (cartItems, cartItemToAdd) => {

      const existingCartItem = cartItems.find(
        cartItem => cartItem.id === cartItemToAdd.id
      );
      if (existingCartItem) {
        return cartItems.map(cartItem =>
          cartItem.id === cartItemToAdd.id
            ? { ...cartItem, quantity: cartItem.quantity + 1 }
            : cartItem
        );
      }
      return [...cartItems, {...cartItemToAdd, quantity: 1 }];
    };```

Answer (score -1):

The id's in cart item must not be unique if it's still giving you that answer. Although it's not best to use this, you can always add the index into the key. It's not best practice to add the index if that list is going to change.

```
{cartItems.map((cartItem, index) => (
     <CartItem key={index} item={cartItem}/>
    ))}
```

Answer (score -1):

It could be because id of your data is not unique.
Please try with index value of map, and if there are no error, then it must unique problem of id and please check array data.